# Trying to Extract Numeric from a text field

Tags: regex, regexp-substr, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have field with different text entered with a 13 or 17 Digit ID.Need to extract that ID from this field

```
 regexp_substr(TXT,'CTRL ACDV\\s+(\\d+)',1,1,'ie')..
```

Txt can can be like this

```
 SUPPRESSED AND FORWARDING CTRL{ACDV 36608732875895776 } {DRID 12345

   SUPPRESSED AND FORWARDING CTRL 9809770899005 TO FRAUD DUE TO ID TH

   SUPPRESSED AND FORWARDING CTRL ACDV 987878829039161097 .DRID 87569
```

```
regexp_substr(TXT,'CTRL ACDV\\s+(\\d+)',1,1,'ie')..
```

need to get

```
36608732875895776
9809770899005 
987878829039161097
```

Comment: HI @CodeManiac...Thank you for the quick response.Tried this regexp_substr(TXT,'(?<=CTRL ADCV\s+)(?:\d{13}|\d{17})',1,1,'ie') got an error back "Invalid regular expression: '(?<=CTRL ADCVs+)(?:d{13}|d{17})', no argument for repetition operator: ?"Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is the space after `CTRL ADCV` is consistent ? if yes than just remmove `+` after `\s`

Comment: @CodeManiac..Yes the spaces are consistent.Removed the + after \s but still gettign the same error.Invalid regular expression: '(?<=CTRL ADCVs)(?:d{13}|d{17})', no argument for repetition operator: ?

Comment: You can see the working [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TC2EOV/1/) here

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume the digits are a minimum length, this works for your 3 examples:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('SUPPRESSED AND FORWARDING CTRL{ACDV 36608732875895776 } {DRID 12345',
                      '(\\d{13,})', 1,1, 'e');

SELECT regexp_substr('SUPPRESSED AND FORWARDING CTRL 9809770899005 TO FRAUD DUE TO ID TH',
                      '(\\d{13,})', 1,1, 'e');

SELECT regexp_substr('SUPPRESSED AND FORWARDING CTRL ACDV 987878829039161097 .DRID 87569',
                      '(\\d{13,})', 1,1, 'e');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only big numbers are the ID's, then this is the shortest and fastest:

```
\d{13,17}
```

Test it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/32HDw1/1).

---

Be aware that the third ID (`987878829039161097`) is actually 18 digits long.

Therefore, if the minimum length is 13, you may want to use:

```
\d{13,}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to delete everything except the long ID's, you can search for the regex:

```
([^\d]+|\d{,12})
```

and replace it with \n (= new line) or whatever you want (e.g. a space).

Test it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/4eLqaK/1).

You may get better result if you do the replace in two steps. First for:

```
[^\d]+
```

(for non-digits)

and then for:

```
\s\d{1,12}(\s|$)
```

(for numbers with less than 13 digits)

Comment: hi i tried it but its giving me null values codes i tried .*\bCTRL\D+(\d{13,18})\b.* and \d{13,17}.Any help is apperciated,

Comment: I do not understand what null values you get. Will you please provide additional details? Why do you need a complicated expression, as you suggested?

Comment: when i use this formula regexp_substr(TXT,'( '\d{13,17}').Its not giving me any results.Just showing as Null.

Comment: In the formula you have '( ' - but in the text (the one you posted in the question), you so not have a '(', but only '{'. Also, you do not have any symbol ( '(' or '{' ) followed by digits. You have "{ACDV"

Comment: Should I understand that you want to delete the parts like "SUPPRESSED AND FORWARDING CTRL{ACDV " ? And only keep the long ID's?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.So the text will be anything as it a random text..The text i provided above is an example.The only goal is i need to get the 13 or 17 digit ID.The text can be anything and the ID can be anywhere in the text.I need to get only the Long ID's as i need this IDs to join to other table and get the data from those tables.

Comment: so the formula will be somwthing like this regexp_replace(TXT,'[^\d]+') as ACDVT
  ,regexp_replace(ACDVT,'\s\d{1,12}(\s|$)')

Comment: I do not know the syntax for `regexp_replace()`. I suppose you need a third parameter, the replacement string, e.g. '\n' or ' '.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a capturing group and use the (from the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html)) `e parameter to return only the part of the string that matches the first sub-expression in the pattern`.

Note that the last number are 18 digits instead of 17.

```
\bCTRL\D+(\d{13,18})
```

**Explanation**

- `\bCTRL` Match word boundary and CTRL
- `\D+` Match 1+ times not a digit
- `(\d{13,18})` Capture 1 group 1 matching 13 - 18 digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RndBuJ/1)

Another option is to match 13 or more digits using `\d{13,}`

The [docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html) state that the patterns are implicitly anchored at both ends, in that case you could use:

```
.*\bCTRL\D+(\d{13,18})\b.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RndBuJ/4)